# Pass dynamic model data to javascript via button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following html table which contains two buttons. 
Both buttons are handled by the same click handler.

```
 <div id="replaceme">

</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <input name="edit" class="edit button" type="button" value="edit" />
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <input name="edit" class="edit button" type="button" value="edit" />
    </tr>
</table>
```

When i click one of those buttons, the following javascript gets executed:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function (event) {
   document.getElementById("replaceme").innerHTML +="textshouldbedynamic <br/>";
});
```

This works, and the text in 'replaceme' div is replaced properly.

Question:
I want do this in a table which is created via asp.net mvc while iterating on a list which is part of my model. 
I now like to put parts of my model into the javascript function. 
pseudo code:

```
<tr>
    <input name="edit" class="edit button" type="button" value="edit" data="foo"/>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <input name="edit" class="edit button" type="button" value="edit" data="bar"/>
</tr>
```

How can i get such data dynamically into a javascript function?

**edit:** 
Is it a correct solution to add a json string, and parse it in the javascript function?

```
<div id="replaceme">

</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <input name="edit" class="edit button" type="button" value="edit" id='{"FirstValue":11,"SecondValue":42}' />
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <input name="edit" class="edit button" type="button" value="edit" id='{"FirstValue":22,"SecondValue":33}'/>
    </tr>
</table>



 $(document).on('click', '.edit', function (event) {
       document.getElementById("replaceme").innerHTML +="textshouldbedynamic <br/>";

        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( this.id );

        document.getElementById("replaceme").innerHTML += obj.FirstValue + " " + obj.SecondValue + "<br/>";
    });
```

[jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5Vvc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about template binding with a client side framework like KnockoutJs?

Comment: I'm new to javascript, and like to learn it without frameworks at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

on asp.net mvc the code rendered on server side and js is a client side languge you can not make the javascript to run on server .
however you can make a call for javascript to run on client side on ready state.
let say you want to run:

```
function foo(data){
//Do somthing
}
```

so you can bind to onready event this call :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.edit button').each(function(){
      val data = $(this).attr('data');
      foo(data);
   });
});
```

is that what you needed?